Sending email via pipe to mailx seems to hang
The system in use is running Debian 11 with the distro provided bsd-mailx.
I have a number of scripts that can send email if something is wrong and one that runs daily and always send a message. The daily email is usually deleted, the subject line has the most pertinent info, so it wasn't until recently that I discovered the body was empty. Before putting it into a cron job I did verify that it worked and continued to work after adding it to my crontab. Some basic troubleshooting lead me to mailx as the issue. The script uses mailx via a pipe for the body, a -s for the subject, a -r for the sender(to remove the system name), and finally a -- followed by the email to send to.
When I attempt to send an email using a pipe, just like the script with `echo 'test' | mailx -s "subject" -r email.from@domain -- email.to@domain, mailx seems to freeze like it is awaiting a body. I can type and press enter to get a new line but hitting CTRL-D does not exit like one would expect. To exit from this state I have to use CTRL-Z to send it to the background as even CTRL-C doesn't work. Running 'jobs' shows that mailx is still running and once brought to the foreground it exits and I get the email. Anything entered before hitting CTRL-Z does not get sent.
Testing mailx without a pipe does allow me to enter a body and hit CTLR-D but then I get a Cc: prompt when I have no intention of sending this to anyone else. Hitting enter does not seem to exit the program.
